# node-mysql callback is not a function

Tags: node.js, express, node-mysql

So i've been searching around the website for a soultion and came across something that has worked for a user previously and tried to copy how it was done just to test out using a callback function to return a result from a query would work, but I'm having problems. Here's my code

**dbfunctions.js**

```
   const connection = require('../helpers/connection');

   function getUserInfo(userID, dynamicField, callback) {
    var query = connection.query("SELECT * FROM subgutter WHERE name = 'random'");
    query.on('result', function(row) {
        callback(null, "row.dynamicField");
    });
  };

  module.exports = getUserInfo();
```

**g.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../helpers/connection');
const dbfunctions = require('../helpers/dbfunctions.js');

 dbfunctions.getUserInfo(8, "test", function(err, result) {
    console.log(err || result);
});
```

this is giving me 
   in dbfunctions.js **callback is not a function**

**Not sure why there's a down-vote if someone could tell me how I can improve this question I'd appreciate it..?**

Comment: Check to see if callback is undefined inside the `on result` event trigger.

Comment: yes it is undefined, do you know why this is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to export `getUserInfo` as  `module.exports.getUserInfo = getUserInfo;` or `module.exports = {getUserInfo:getUserInfo}`. In your case module.exports is the result of getUserInfo() (called without argument) and this throws your error.

Comment: This works, but I have a follow up question. Is there a way to set the callback result to  a variable without making the variable global?

 `let gutterId = null;
  dbfunctions.gutterNameToId("random", function(result) {
        gutterId = result;
    }); `

Comment: If you define your variable in a given scope, it will be accessible only for upper scopes. In your example gutterId is global but you can do `function(result) { let gutterId = result; })` and process your data in your callback function.